# userId missing over react js with firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am having trouble sending the userId to my collection on firebase and the only thing that sends is "userId : undefined". What shall I put on the field userId?

```
class AddTopic extends Component {
 state = {
 userName: "",
 topic: "",
 date: "",
 userId: `${this.userId}`
};

onSubmit = e => {
 e.preventDefault();

 const newTopic = this.state;

 const { firestore, history } = this.props;

 firestore
   .add({ collection: "topics" }, newTopic)
   .then(() => history.push("/"));
 };
```

Comment: Your state constructor is evaluated only once, if `this.userId` is undefined, the string for userId will evaluate to an empty string. Where are you setting this.userId, it doesn't look like you are.

Comment: thanks for replying, I am new to react js, where shall I set "this.userId"? Regards,

Comment: It would most likely come from the Props.